# Only printing last line of txt file when reading into struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, loops, struct

I am reading from a txt file into an array of structures. Example txt:

```
-4.5 -1 0 0
4.0 1 0 0
8 0 1 2
12.1 0 -6 1
-3.2 2.5 -3.0 4
```

The 4 values of each line correspond to the 4 values in the structure. The file may contain up to 100 lines (MAX is defined as 100). With the following code I am trying to store each line into the respective index of the struct array and then print:

```
FILE *fileName = NULL;
typedef struct chargeData_struct {
    double Q, x, y, z;
} ChargeData;
ChargeData values[MAX], *p = values;

fileName = fopen("charge2.txt", "r");
if (fileName == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR: Could not open file.");
}

int k = 0;
while (fscanf(fileName, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &p[k].Q, &p[k].x, &p[k].y, &p[k].z) != EOF);
{
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", p[k].Q, p[k].x, p[k].y, p[k].z);
    k++;
}
fclose(fileName);
```

However, only the last line of the txt file is printed. Is the same index of the struct array being overwritten each time?

Comment: `while (...) ; { ... }` --> `while (...) { ... }`

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of the `while` statement. It gives it an empty code block and then the intended code is run once, after the while loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extra semicolon which makes all the trouble, here:

```
while (fscanf(...) != EOF);
{
   ...
```

Remove it and you should be fine.

What happens with your code is that `while(..);` is equivalent to this:

```
while(...)
{
    ; // do nothing
}
```

thus does not enter the body (the one you think is the body) of your loop (since the actual body does nothing). However `scanf()` continues to parse the file, and then this section of your code executes:

```
{
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", p[k].Q, p[k].x, p[k].y, p[k].z);
    k++;
}
```

independently, where the curly braces are treated like they wanted to state scope.

Comment: Thank you! That totally escaped my eye.

Comment: You are welcome @JeffJohnson, do not forget to *accept* the answer, since you liked it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER_LEN   (512)
#define RESERVE_NEWLINDE          0
#define AUTO_FILTER_NEWLINDE      1

typedef int (* LINE_READER)(char * pstrLine, int uiBufferLen, void * pvData);

typedef struct st_HW_SSP_CONFIG
{
    const char * pstrConfigPath;
    LINE_READER pfLineReader;
    FILE * pstFile;
    void * pvData;
    int CurrentLine;
    int Flag;
} CONFIG_ST;

int CloseConfig(CONFIG_ST * pstConfig)
{
    if (!pstConfig)
    {
        // record error
        return -1;
    }
    if (fclose(pstConfig->pstFile))
    {
        // record error
    }
    return 0;
}

int OpenConfigFile(const char * pstrFilePath, CONFIG_ST * pstConfig)
{
    FILE * pstFile = NULL;
    if ((!pstrFilePath) || (!pstConfig))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    pstFile = fopen(pstrFilePath, "r");
    if (!pstFile)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    pstConfig->pstFile = pstFile;
    pstConfig->pstrConfigPath = pstrFilePath;
    pstConfig->Flag = RESERVE_NEWLINDE;
    return 0;
}

int IsNullStr(const char *pcStr)
{
    const char *pcTmp = pcStr;
    while ('\0' != *pcTmp)
    {
        if (!isspace(*pcTmp))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        pcTmp++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int IsEffectiveLine(char acFileLineBuffer[LINE_BUFFER_LEN])
{
    if (0 == strlen(&acFileLineBuffer[0]))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ('#' == acFileLineBuffer[0]) // strip as a comment line
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (IsNullStr(&acFileLineBuffer[0]))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void FilterNewLine(char* pcLine,  int MaxNumLen)
{
    int uiLen = strlen(pcLine);
    if (uiLen > 1)
    {
        if ('\n' == pcLine[uiLen - 1])
        {
            pcLine[uiLen - 1] = '\0';

            if (uiLen > 2)
            {
                if ('\r' == pcLine[uiLen - 2])
                {
                    pcLine[uiLen - 2] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

int ReadConfigFile(CONFIG_ST * pstConfig)
{
    char acFileLineBuffer[LINE_BUFFER_LEN] = {0};
    char * pstrRead = NULL;
    int Ret = 0;

    if (!pstConfig)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((!pstConfig->pstFile) || (!pstConfig->pfLineReader))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    rewind(pstConfig->pstFile);
    pstConfig->CurrentLine = 0;

    do
    {
        memset((void *)&acFileLineBuffer[0], 0, LINE_BUFFER_LEN);
        pstrRead = fgets(&acFileLineBuffer[0], LINE_BUFFER_LEN - 1, pstConfig->pstFile);
        if (pstrRead)
        {
            pstConfig->CurrentLine ++;

            if (0 == IsEffectiveLine(acFileLineBuffer))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (AUTO_FILTER_NEWLINDE == pstConfig->Flag)
            {
                FilterNewLine(acFileLineBuffer, LINE_BUFFER_LEN - 1);
            }

            if (pstConfig->pfLineReader)
            {
                Ret = pstConfig->pfLineReader(&acFileLineBuffer[0],
                                              LINE_BUFFER_LEN,
                                              pstConfig->pvData);

                if (Ret)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (pstrRead);
    return Ret;
}

int ReadConfigFileEx(const char * pFilePath,
                     LINE_READER pfReader,
                     void * pData, int Flag)
{
    int Ret = 0;
    CONFIG_ST stConfig = {0};

    Ret = OpenConfigFile(pFilePath, &stConfig);
    if (Ret)
    {
        return Ret;
    }

    stConfig.pfLineReader = pfReader;
    stConfig.pvData = pData;
    stConfig.Flag = Flag;
    Ret = ReadConfigFile(&stConfig);
    CloseConfig(&stConfig);
    return Ret;
}


int StringSplit(char *pcStr, char cFlag,
                char * pstArray[], int MaxNum,
                int *pNum)
{
    char * pcStrTemp = 0;
    unsigned int uiIndex = 0;

    pcStrTemp = pcStr;

    while (pcStrTemp)
    {
        pstArray[uiIndex] = pcStrTemp;
        pcStrTemp = strchr(pcStrTemp, cFlag);
        if (pcStrTemp)
        {
            *pcStrTemp = '\0';
            pcStrTemp ++;
            uiIndex ++;
        }
        if (uiIndex >= MaxNum)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (0 != MaxNum)
    {
        *pNum = uiIndex >= MaxNum ? (MaxNum - 1) : uiIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        *pNum = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int MyLineReader(char * pstrLine, int uiBufferLen, void * pvData)
{
    printf("Read line:[%s]\r\n", pstrLine);

    char *pArray[8] = {0};
    int Num = 0;
    int index = 0;
    StringSplit(pstrLine, ' ', pArray, 8, &Num);
    for (index = 0; index <= Num; index ++)
    {
        printf("Get value :[%s]\r\n", pArray[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Please input file to read.\r\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ret = ReadConfigFileEx(argv[1], MyLineReader, NULL, AUTO_FILTER_NEWLINDE);
    if (ret)
    {
        printf("Open file error.\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```