# Reading lines of txt file into array prints only the last element

Tags: c++

First of all, I didn't code in C++ for more then 8 years, but there is a hobby project I would like to work on where I ran into this issue.

I checked a similar question: [Only printing last line of txt file when reading into struct array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423939/only-printing-last-line-of-txt-file-when-reading-into-struct-array-in-c)
but in my case I don't have a semicolon at the end of the while cycle.

Anyway, so I have a `nicknames.txt` file where I store nicknames, one in each line.
Then I want to read these nicknames into an array and select one random element of it.
Example `nicknames.txt`:

```
alpha
beta
random nickname
...
Pirate Scrub
```

Then I read the TXT file:

```
    int nicknameCount = 0;
    char *nicknames[2000];

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file("nicknames.txt");
    FILE *fileID = fopen("asd.txt", "w");

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        nicknames[nicknameCount++] = line.data();
        // (1)
        fprintf(fileID, "%i: %s\n", nicknameCount - 1, nicknames[nicknameCount - 1]);
    }

    int randomNickIndex = rand() % nicknameCount;

    // (2)
    for (int i = 0; i < nicknameCount; i++)
        fprintf(fileID, "%i: %s\n", i, nicknames[i]);

    fprintf(fileID, "Result: %s\n", nicknames[randomNickIndex]);
    fprintf(fileID, "Result: %i\n", randomNickIndex);
    fclose(fileID);
    exit(0);
```

What then I see at point (1) is what I expect; the nicknames. Then later at point (2) every single member of the array is "Pirate Scrub", which is the last element of the `nicknames.txt`.

I think it must be something obvious, but I just can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: why are you mixing C and C++ i/o?

Comment: the q/a you link is about C. Note that C and C++ are two different languages. There is no reason to mix them here

Comment: sorry, it's only a few hours I'm trying to remember the language, so things come back very slowly

Comment: Forget char* in C++, use std::string.

Comment: the thing is, you should forget more ;). Don't use `fopen`, `char*` nor `fprintf` unless you absolutely need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line.data()` returns a pointer to the sequence of characters. It is always the same pointer. Every time you read a new line, the contents of `line` are overwritten. To fix this, you will need to copy the contents of `line`.

Change:

```
char *nicknames[2000];
```

to

```
char nicknames[2000][256];
```

and

```
nicknames[nicknameCount++] = line.data();
```

to

```
strcpy(nicknames[nicknameCount++], line.data());
```

However, using a vector to store the lines is probably better, since this is C++

Comment: This solved the issue, it was fast, so I mark, this as solution, but upvote the others as well. I knew it will be something obvious x)

Answer (score 1):

Your `nicknames` array does not contain copies of the strings, all the nicknames are pointers to the same data owned by `line`.

Instead of `char* nicknames[2000]` i would recommend you use

```
std::vector<std::string> nicknames;
```

and then inside the loop:

```
nicknames.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char *nicknames[2000];
```

is an array of 2000 pointers to `char`. Nowhere in your code you are actually storing the strings from the file. This

```
nicknames[nicknameCount++] = line.data();
```

merely stores pointers to the `line`s internal buffer in the array. In the next iteration this buffer is overwritten with contents of the next line.

Forget about all the C i/o. Mixing C and C++ is advanced and you don't need it here. If you want to store a dynamically sized array of strings in C++, that is a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
 std::vector<std::string> lines;
 std::string line;
 while (std::getline(file, line))
 {
    lines.push_back(line);
 }
```

Also for writing to the output file you should use an `std::ofstream`.